# I want method to run (event to occur) while i am typing something in textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application, windows-forms-designer

I want method to run (event to occur) while i am typing something in textbox ( i dont want to click button)      for example i have a a textbox and a listbox in a same form and while i am writing text in textbox it should simultaneously print that in listbox without clicking an button

Comment: Look at the TextChanged event of the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Text Changed event for your textbox
[*Text Changed* event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXwUu.png)

Comment: As i was typing something in textbox so it was printing in listbox at the same time without pressing of any button through TEXT CHANGED event

Comment: Now if i have written any alphabet wrong and i press backspace to remove it from textbox so i want it to be removed from the list box as well

Comment: how to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the `TextBox` control's `TextChanged` [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

> This event is raised if the Text property is changed by either a programmatic modification or user interaction.
>   For more information about handling events, see [Handling and Raising Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index).

You can access it through the properties list, or you can create it at `Initialize` or `Form_Load` or even in the `Form` constructor using:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: As i was typing something in textbox so it was printing in listbox at the same time without pressing of any button through TEXT CHANGED event

Comment: Now if i have written any alphabet wrong and i press backspace to remove it from textbox so i want it to be removed from the list box as well how to do it please?

Comment: @programminghub Please create a new question here on StackOverflow and show us what you're currently trying and tell us about the effect you desire in full detail and we will help you!